# Show another storyboard while WebView is loading then switch back to original storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview

I'm making an app in Xcode and the main storyboard is just a WebView element and while its loading its just it displays a white screen however while its loading I want it to switch to another storyboard(which would be a loading screen) then when its finished loading the WebView element I want it to switch back to Main.Storyboard. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using WKWebView?

Comment: Yes! Il add the code to the question!

Comment: import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var WebView: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.23:5000/")//Defines the URL for the WebView
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        
        WebView.load(request)

    }
    
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool
        {
        return true
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add loader in UIWebView by using Activity Indicator,

```
@IBOutlet var loader: UIActivityIndicatorView!

func webViewDidStartLoad(_ : UIWebView) {
loader.startAnimating()
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ : UIWebView) {
    loader.stopAnimating()
}
```

Don't forget set delegate to UIViewController of web view.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var WebView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.23:5000/")//Defines the URL for the WebView
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        WebView.load(request)

    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool
        {
        return true
    }
}
```